# iOS how to stop view rotate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want my iPad app to stop rotation as you rotate the iPad. I want to stop rotate every view.

Any ideas help?

Answer (score 10):

if you want stop rotation for whole app then simply in app info.plist file changed **Supported interface orientations** ,**Initial interface orientation** property to portrait or landscape depends on you

Comment: This is so easy and useful. Is there a way to override it in one view Controller? I have 10 view controllers and one of them needs to be in landscape but the rest I have used this method to restrict to portrait orientation only.

Comment: If this is the case you have to override methods   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return __orientation;
} in every view Controller

Answer (score 5):

Just check the auto-resizing property of your view controller.

(Fixed syntax error)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In iOS6 `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` has be deprecated. Override both `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` instead.

[Please see](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:)

Comment: Your [Please see](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) link no longer works

Answer (score 1):

In My Project's `info.plist` I have deleted some key on the iPad `Supported interface orientations` like the following image (I have only given support for the portrait orientation)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of global controllable rotation lock is to write UIViewController category containing lock mechanism for every view controller.

You simply need to modify `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method globally

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return __orientation;
}
```

Here `__orientation` is the static variable which can be set via category method.

The full realization of the category is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25224863/2066428)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please update your projectname.plist like this. Supported interface orientations have only one object "Portrait (bottom home button)"

Answer (score -3):

I strongly advise against stop rotation on iPad because supporting rotation is a must on the iPad. This is because the iPad does not have a normal way in which it will be held unlike the iPhone, which is normally held in portrait view (AKA Vertical). So you have to leave the choice to the user to eventually lock the orientation

The HIG do not actually state this as a requirement, but as a recommendation but there are many app that was rejected by this issue.

By the way if you want to this for a limit number of view controller you should implement:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        return YES;
    }
}
```