# How to rotate the ipad screen using code in my ios app

Tags: ios, screen, rotation

When my app is launched, it is initially in portrait orientation.  It can rotate when the ipad device is physically rotated.

I hope to add a function that allows users to click a button to open a help tutorial.  I want the tutorial to only be landscape.

So I override the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method to check if the app is in help tutorial mode; returning 'Yes' if it is:

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
    interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)`
```

When the screen is in portrait, and the user clicks the button to open the help tutorial, how do I rotate the screen to landscape at the beginning of my button response code?

Answer (score 0):

If the controller with the help tutorial doesn't support Portrait, it will automatically show the image in Landscape mode, even if the user doesn't hold the device like that, you shouldn't need to "rotate" the screen yourself, through code.

If you want to rotate your view manually (but NOT change the device orientation), use this code for a 90 degrees rotation

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
self.view.transform = transform;
```

M_PI_2 = 90 degrees

M_PI = 180 degrees

Comment: but my app support all orientation. here is my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: mothod. - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (tutorialModeOn == NO)
        return YES;
    else
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    }
}

Comment: The app itself can support all orientations, but a view controller can have different settings, to support only a single orientation, if needed. They are different things

Comment: how do I limit my view controller to a landscape orientation by a coding mean. The tutorial in my app is a scrollview added to the main view.

Comment: like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5296430/855738 but use Landscape instead of portrait

Comment: when the mainView is portrait, and user click a button to open the tutorial, and the tutorial is a set imageviews added to a scrollview. How do I init the landscape scrollview in a portrait mode. I have found a method UIDevice setOrientation: can force the orientation with code, but unfortunately  the method cannot use in the latest ios.