# how to lock portrait orientation for only view in ios 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, landscape-portrait

I have created an application for Iphone and Ipad that is composed from two main views with navigation controller. The navigation controllers are inserted into tabBar controller.
I would like lock the main views to Portrait orientation and only a subview of a navigation controller trigger the possibility orintation to Partrait and Landscape.
Is it possible?
How Can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Both answers given so far are wrong.

Here's what you do:

Make sure you list portrait and landscape in the list of supported orientations in your info.plist file. (The default app templates include all orientations for iPad, and all but portrait upside-down for iPhone, which is probably what you want.)

You want to implement the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations:` in the view controllers that you want to limit to portrait:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Any view controllers that include that code will only support portrait. All others will support all the orientations listed in your info.plist.

The older method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is only needed if you support OS versions prior to 6.0.

You also only need to implement the method shouldAutorotate if you might return NO (don't rotate) sometimes.)

Comment: I have seen info.plist file at Supported interface orientations (iPad). Into info.pilist file are included: Landscape (right home button), Landscape (left home button) and Portrait (bottom home button). I tried your method above in the class that I want to lock, but turn orientation always

Comment: That answer will not override orientations set in plist

Comment: @JSA986, yes it will. The plist provides a list of all **POSSIBLE** orientations you app can support. Then, if you implement the supportedInterfaceOrientations method, you can limit the orientations that a given view controller supports. I have used this repeatedly in applications that are in the app store. It most definitely works.

Comment: @Ducnan It does not work for me, (and just tested it) or the OP?

Comment: It goes deeper than your answer past iOS 6, your method wont even get called >iOS6, OP needs to subclass parent view/nav controller

Comment: @JSA986, you mean the method won't get called for iOS < 6.0, don't you?

Comment: You are right about the nav controller. It takes some extra work to make a navigation controller manage rotation on child view controllers correctly. What I've done in the past is to subclass UINavigatonController and have the nav controller ask the current top view controller what orientations it supports.

Comment: So If I have a view controller with nav controller, Can I implement the method (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations into the view controller's class in the way that it works ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the universal approach based on the category for `UIViewController` with method swizzling.

```
//  UIViewController+Orientation.h
@interface UIViewController (Orientation)

- (void)setOrientation:(NSUInteger)orientation;

@end

//  UIViewController+Orientation.m
#import "UIViewController+Orientation.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static NSUInteger __orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

@implementation UIViewController (Orientation)

+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;
    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(viewWillDisappear:));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_viewWillDisappear:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (void)swizzled_viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    __orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    [self swizzled_viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return __orientation;
}

- (void)setOrientation:(NSUInteger)orientation
{
    __orientation = orientation;
}

@end
```

Now you can fix orientation of any controller by setting `orientation` in `viewWillAppear:`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Swizzling cares for autorelease orientation lock on controller change.

This approach works for all types of controllers including situation of TabbarViewController and UINavigationController which in fact reply to rotation events.

One can even make a lock button in the app which will get current orientation and set it as fixed via the category.

Comment: Saved my day, night, week :-) Cheers! [Working on iOS 8 too]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Sure you can do this.

Below code force view controller for landscape,
You can modify for portrait.
i use it for iPhone.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(270));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    //NSLog(@"%f %f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.width, self.height); 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, y, self.width, 44.0);
    [appdelegate stopProgressIndicator];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
    CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
    [[self navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.height, self.width);
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, y, self.height, 44.0);

}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Is there the method that set every view to Portrait or Landscape in IOS? For example in appDelegate I used: (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

Comment: ok...
Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645782/force-orientation-to-portrait-mode
Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

put this in all classes....

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue]<7.0) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
        }else{
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        }
    }
    -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

        return NO;
    }
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] integerValue]<7.0) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
            return YES;
        }else{
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
        }

        return NO;
    }
```